# How to troubleshoot redis connection?

Tags: redis, elastic-cache

I am provisioning one ElasticCache instance via https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-elasticache-redis?ref=0.52.0

The instance is created fine with cluster_mode disabled and just with 1 node (as per my request and desired output).

So far all is good!

The security group of the Redis allows access from my EC2 security group.

Inside the ec2 I can telnet to the `primary endpoint`

```
root@ip-x-x-x-x:/d# telnet master.api-cache-dev.xxxh77s.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com 6379 
Trying 10.40.62.56...
Connected to api-cache-dev-001.api-cache-dev.xxx77s.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

BUT if I try to connect to this Redis it hangs forever:

```
redis-cli -h master.api-cache-dev.xxxh77s.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

I let this command run for 30 minutes and did nothing.

In comparison when I created the redis via another terraform module I could connect fine though.

**My question is:**
How to understand what is going on and fix the issue ?
I am lost atm

This is how the elastic cache looks in AWS:
[image]